# C# webclient on WIFI

Tags: c#

I implemented a simple Webclient to upload files to a web server. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
 private bool fileUploadValid = new bool();
    string fileLocation = "D:/testvideo.avi";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCallback);

        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");

        UploadFileInBackground("http://xxx/videolibrary/fileUpload.php", fileLocation);
    }

    public void UploadFileInBackground(string address, string fileName)
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri(address);
        client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", fileLocation);


        Console.WriteLine("File upload started.");
       // fileUploadValid = false;

    }
```

When I try to upload a file over wifi it is very slow (although my wifi signal strength is perfect). The uploads stops about every 5 seconds and then most often continues but sometimes doesnt. The stopping of the upload is my biggest problem because it will not throw any error (no timeout or anything else). When I connect my laptop to a ethernet cable there is no problem and the upload finishes in no time. Can somebody help me out?

I also tried the same code at my University, where it seems to work fine. There is a WPA netwerk there where I am here on a WEP signed netwerk.

Comment: Have you tried running a speedtest on your wifi? Webclient does not distinguish between Wifi v/s ethernet (it is actually on a different OSI layer).

Comment: ping 21ms downloadspeed 0.27mbs uploadspeed 0.86mbs

Comment: The file is 3 mb and takes more than 3 minutes to complete. The biggest problem is that i see it freezing on the upload progress callback, any ideas?

Comment: what does the speed look like on ethernet, much faster I'd assume. Try uploading a smaller file. My gut feel is that there is a timeout somewhere, either at webclient or at server. If the infrastructure is the problem, there is only so much you can do in the code (ex- break-up into parts etc).

Comment: I understand your answer, but when I use an FTP client I can upload the file in 10 seconds to the same server. I also had the feeling it would be a timeout but I set the timeout on the php.ini file on the server and also max_input_time , upload_max_filesize, post_max_size. I also tried extending the webclient with a delay without any effect

Comment: hmm, do you see anything logged in the EventLog? Can you try using a tool like `WireShark` to check whats happening at the network traffic level?

Answer (score 0):

Do you or your neighbors own any of the following: [Microwave, Smartphone, Another Wifi AP, Bluetooth radio, DECT cordless phone, Car, Zigbee or any other 2.4GHz radio source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz)? It sounds like there is intermittent dropped packets in your network. Remember there are multiple elements that can drop the ball in a network. In the residential setting I personally find that the Wifi PHY layer performs very very badly (but good enough for most people, since the TCP stack tends to handle dropped packets well).

Offices tend not to have so many 2.4GHz sources as at home.

Try disconnecting your neighbors' electrical appliances. A small EMP device should suffice^. Alternatively you could try shielding your house from your neighbors' EM emissions using the tin foil wall paper, constructing what is called a [Faraday Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Remember to include a [tin foil hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat)*. This will reduce the EM emissions from your brain interfering with the transfer.

Also try isolating your WIFI appliances from the mains. Attach them using surge protectors, this can help to reduces interference from appliances such as your washing machine and TV (or in my case, once, a pair of [HomePlugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)) that can cause line noise from generating radio noise.

Finally you can try to switch your WIFI channel to 5GHz if they all work on that frequency. Its meant to be clearer. However, ultimately as more people use the 2.4GHz radio range, WIFI will get worse.

^This SO user does not condone the usage of electronic/nuclear warfare weaponry for the purpose of reducing dropped packets on you home wifi.

*NB The tin foil hat is included for humor as I do know how constructing a Faraday Cage in your house will look to your neighbors.